# How do I prevent SDL from scaling textures when resizing a window?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am building a gui library for a project I am working on. I would like it to behave like a normal gui library where widgets don't resize to fit in the window but stay at the same size I initially render it at. How do I achieve this in SDL2?

Comment: what flags do you pass to `SDL_CreateWindow`?

Comment: SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I was calling SDL_RenderCopy() with NULL for the destination rect. You need to have a rect with the fixed values you want to render the text at. When the window resizes the text will continue to draw at the same size and position. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: You saved my day. It was exactly what I needed. Thank you many times!)